# file_get_contents ошибка denwer

Tags: php, mysql, denwer

```
<?if (!$_GET['code']) {
exit('error code');}
include 'config.php';
$token = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://oauth.vk.com/access_token?client_id='.ID.'&redirect_uri='.URL.'&client_secret='.SECRET.'&code='.$_GET['code']), 
true);

if (!$token) {
exit('error token');
}


$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_id='.$token['user_id'].'&access_token='.$token['access_token'].'&fields=uid
,first_name,last_name,photo_big'), true);

if (!$data) {
exit('error data');
}

$data = $data['response'][0];

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($data);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

выдает ошибку:

> file_get_contents(https://oauth.vk.com/access_token?client_id=620**57&redirect_uri=https://mysite/vk.php&client_secret=7*****IFrku32EloUowf1&code=8d6b63f6d8f5d454d7):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
>   in Z:\home\mysite\www\vk.php on line 9 error token

php файл с константами

```
define('ID', '*******');
define('SECRET', '**********');
define('URL', 'https://mysite/vk.php');
```

Делал по примеру, что неправильно уже пол дня не могу понять

Comment: вы уверены, что `id` и `secret` стоит публиковать открыто?

Comment: А зачем куча пробелов после access_token?

Comment: немного криво оформил вопрос, исправил все
ошибка все же в другом я думаю

Comment: Используйте OpenServer

Comment: Denwer устарел. используйте OpenServer

Comment: поставил Openserver ошибка та де самая, значит дело не в Denwere

Comment: OpenServer предлагался не как решение, а как удобство =)

Answer (score 0):

```
function curl_get_contents($url)
{
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
}

$url = 'https://...';
$json = json_decode(curl_get_contents($url));
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20562368/file-get-contents-how-to-fix-error-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file)